# Hashtag to a normal Text

Tags: jquery, hashtag

How can I transform a hashtag into a normal text?

**Ex:**

```html
<div class="hashtag">Hello #my_best_friend, you are #welcome</div>
```

**Result:** 
Hello my best friend, you are welcome

Comment: `console.log($('.hashtag').first().html().replace(/#/g, ''));`

Comment: @RavishaHesh that won't remove the underscores.

Comment: `console.log($('.hashtag').first().html().replace(/#/g, '').replace('/_/g', ' '));`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to replace the unwanted characters using `String#replace` with the help of RegExps:

```js
$('.hashtag').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();

  $(this).text(
    text
    .replace(/#(\w+)/g, '$1')
    .replace(/_/g, ' ')
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hashtag">Hello #my_best_friend, you are #welcome</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your browser support zero-width positive lookbehind assertion, then you could use following regular expression to replace unwanted symbols in hash-tag with spaces:

```js
var src = $('.hashtag').text();
$('.hashtag').text(src.replace(/((^|\s)#(?=\S+)|(?<=#\S+)_)/g, ' '))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hashtag">Hello #my_best_friend, you are #welcome</div>
```

Comment: Yes! it works. Thank you Alexander.

what if i want to wrap the hashtag, so i get this: <div class="hashtag">Hello <em>my best friend</em>, you are <em>welcome</em></div>

Comment: @AbdelkaderBenkhaled, then you have to use [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method instead of [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) and another regular expression. You could build your own expression using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)

Answer (score -2):

Please check out these two pages: [jQuery's replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) and Javascript's [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var string = $('.hashtag').html();  // get the content
  var result = string.replace("#my_best_friend", "my best friend");  // replace keywords
  $('.hashtag').replaceWith( result );  // update the content
});
```